# Can I switch to disc then back to download version?

Tags: ps4, rocket-league

I own Rocket League both disc and download format and I want to sell the disc, but I want to make sure it works before I sell it. When I put the disc in, it says "Do you want to switch to the disc version of this game? The downloaded version will be deleted."

I just want to know if that would completely get rid of my downloaded version or can I get it back?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you choose to replace the digital version with the disc version, **it will be deleted from the console**. However, you will still be able to re-download the digital version (although you will need to delete the disc version).

Answer (score 0):

IF you put the disc in, it screws up the download version.
I did that with terraria. Had to reinstall the download since the disc overwrote it.